# Raising OpenURI::HTTPError caused wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec, open-uri

I am testing how a method handles a 302 HTTPError exception. I tried to stub the one method call to raise one programmatically, however it keep complaining that wrong number of arguments error (0 for 2)

the code tested this particular line:

```
document = Nokogiri.HTML open(source_url)
```

and in the spec I stubbed it like this:

```
subject.stub(:open).and_raise(OpenURI::HTTPError)
subject.should_receive(:ended=).with(true)
subject.update_from_remote
```

I don't think it is related to Nokogiri.HTML() or Open-uri.open(), so why is this happening?

Also, how would I try to make this HTTPError as a 302 redirect error? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that OpenURI::HTTPError's constructor requires two parameters. Rspec by default will call the error class's new method with no parameter, which cause this error. So I need to manually create an error object by passing the required parameters.

```
exception_io = mock('io')
exception_io.stub_chain(:status,:[]).with(0).and_return('302')          
subject.stub(:open).with(anything).and_raise(OpenURI::HTTPError.new('',exception_io))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late reply, but for others who may find this helpful: if you use the [FakeWeb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb) gem in conjunction with Nokogiri, you can do this kind of testing without having to get so involved with the internals of the code. You can register a URI with FakeWeb in your test, and tell it what to return. For example:

```
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, 'http://www.google.com', :status => ['404', 'Not Found'])
```

The URI argument you provide needs to match the URI your method is calling. FakeWeb will then intercept the call, and return the status you provide.